# Buy execution time in DOT on AssetHub

Tags: xcm, assethub, transact, chopsticks

I want to execute `Transact` on AssetHub from another parachain and therefore need to `WithdrawAsset` and `BuyExecution` beforehand.

Unfortunately, I keep running into `FailedToTransactAsset` on AH. I am unsure whether I am referring correctly to the DOT Asset as `Concrete { parents: 1, interior: here }`. I have funded the origin sovereign parachain account with enough DOT.

The pseudo code of the XCM is

```rust
let dot = MultiAsset {
    id: AssetId::Concrete(MultiLocation::parent()),
    fun: Fungibility::Fungible(10_000_000_000), // 1 DOT
};

let xcm_to_send = Xcm(vec![
    WithdrawAsset(dot.clone().into()),
    BuyExecution { fees: dot.into(), weight_limit: WeightLimit::Unlimited },
    Transact {
        origin_kind: OriginKind::Native,
        require_weight_at_most: Weight::from_parts(REF_TIME, PROOF_SIZE),
        call: call.encode().into(),
    },
]);
```

Here's the encoded call data:

```
0x790003010100a10f031400040001000002093d0013000002043205e5140002093d000006010300286bee823801001c000710deadbeef140d0100010100411f
```

I am testing this with Chopsticks. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way how to inspect the nested error of `FailedToTransactAsset` yet.

Comment: Is this `0x790003010100a10f031400040001000002093d0013000002043205e5140002093d000006010300286bee823801001c000710deadbeef140d0100010100411f` the encoded call in `Transact`? for what chain? I can not decode it

Comment: Sorry about that. This hex is the entire `polkadot_xcm::send` call crafted on a custom chain which is not public and would exceed the scope of your help. I know that `send` is usually restricted to root, on my custom chain it is not though. The v1.1.2 Polkadot Runtimes release enables remote accounts to be recognised.

Comment: Can you share the encoded call inside the `Transact`?

Comment: The `Transact` is a simple `remarkWithEvent` call for testing purposes: `0x000710deadbeef`

Comment: The same error (`FailedToTransact("AccountIdConversionFailed")`) occurs when I try to transfer DOT from Polkadot to a remote account on AssetHub `{ parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountId32: { network: Some(...), id: ALICE })}`. Here's the call hex for Polkadot: `0x630903000100a10f0300010101002e36c499d14939b1c69dce0594a78b1534404e7e2e767fa69be3f7eb35a3b2e3d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d0304000000000b008cb6611e010000000000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need to see de decoded call to give an accurate answer, but I can tell that the `origin_kind` in the `Transact` is wrong, try with `OriginKind::SovereignAccount`.

By the way, `remarkWithEvent` will not pass the `AssetHub`'s `SafeCallFilter`.

Comment: Both of your statements are correct. I changed the extrinsic to a transfer and used `SovereignAccount` which lead the call to succeed! Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

I don't exactly know, how the chopsticks runs AssetHub and `polkadot-parachain`, but is it possible to add there `RUST_LOG=xcm=trace` somehow?

Comment: Try to add `runtime-log-level: 5` in your Chopsticks's config file

Comment: Thanks, that certainly adds more logs! Beforehand, I just used `LOG_LEVEL=debug` which was not helpful. Unfortunately, the XCM error is not expanded. AFAICS, I need to build an AssetHub WASM with log lines added by myself. Trying this now.